# Power Source in VENUS

Tags: space-travel, spaceships, power-sources, nuclear-power

**What is the best Power Source to use in VENUS to generate electrical Power by using the properties of the VENUS land? **
I was thinking about the RTG but I found a lot of disadvantages of it.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE! Your question could use some more detail about what you consider "best." For a start, you might elaborate on what you consider are the drawbacks of RTG, which will probably reveal what kind of criteria you have in mind.

Comment: Best is context dependent. Without knowing your specific context determining best is impossible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know which references you're making. I'll leave some time to clarify the question, but otherwise we'll need to vote to close. Is VENUS a video game? RPG? story line? You may be on the wrong stack exchange. Or are you talking about the actual planet? https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/50239/venus-probe-with-refrigerated-electronics-powered-by-an-rtg-more-like-the-mars

Answer (score 1):

**Assumption:** You're talking about the planet, Venus.

Possible ways to generate power on Venus using the planet's natural characteristics:

1. Wind. The average wind speed is around 320 kph.
2. (Very simplistically) if you had copper, the sulfuric acid in the atmosphere could be used to generate electricity, but this would be temporary. It would only work until your copper completely converted to copper sulfate.
3. Thermal. The average surface temperature is 800+ degrees. If you had enough power to initially drill down 100-200 feet to create a thermal sink you could theoretically set up a [thermoelectric generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_generator).

- I doubt you could use solar. I believe the cloud cover is too great for it to work.
- The sulfuric acid in the atmosphere is a *big problem.*
- RTG ([Radioisotope thermoelectric generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator)) doesn't use any aspect of Venus. It's basically a complicated battery that you would bring with you. The device would require mining, refining, and manufacturing on Venus to use Venus to build one (during which time you'd need another power source). If you think RTG is a valid answer to your question, then you did not ask your question well.